collapse_table.py de FAPROTAX lanza FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory para un archivo que debe crearse
Estoy intentando crear una tabla de funciones utilizando este código:
collapse_table.py -i otu_table.tsv -o functional_table.tsv -g FAPROTAX.txt -c "#" -d "taxonomy" --omit_columns 0 --column_names_are_in last_comment_line -r report.txt -n columns_after_collapsing -v

Se supone que el archivo functional_table.tsv debe crearse y no existir en la carpeta desde antes, pero me sale este error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'functional_table.tsv'. 

¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema?


intente pasar a una ruta absoluta al argumento -o pero me sigue dando error


Probe creando una carpeta en descargas que es una de las pocas sin sincronización de Onedrive y ya se logró crear functional_table.tsv. Muchisimas gracias


Hola, sería de gran ayuda que aportaras la traza completa del error (todo lo que te muestra al ejecutar el comando) y no solo el error en si mismo. Esto nos debería dar información de la línea exacta del script dónde se está generando, además, los prints de la opción --verbose (que ya usas) también podrían ayudar.

He intentado reproducir el problema y al menos en Linux no hay ningún error con tus mismos argumentos... Mirando el código fuente tampoco veo claro que puede estar pasando... Este error suele producirse cuando el directorio en el que se intenta crear el archivo no existe (la opción "w" crea el archivo si no existe pero no los directorios de la ruta de no existir). Parce que en Windows tambien se produce en rutas muy largas si no se tiene habilitadas, pero no parece ser tu caso.

Por probar cosas, intenta pasar una ruta absoluta al argumento -o, por ejemplo algo como: collapse_table.py -i otu_table.tsv -o "C:/Users/cindy/OneDrive/Documentos/functional_table.tsv" -g FAPROTAX.txt ...

Me acabo de dar cuenta de un detalle, es posible que sea OneDrive el problema, puede que simplemente esos directorios no existan físicamente en el sistema de archivos... Prueba especificando una ruta existente en tu PC (que todas las carpetas de la ruta existan, menos el archivo final lógicamente) pero fuera de la sincronización de OneDrive, por ejemplo C:/Users/cindy/functional_table.tsv debería valer, al menos para identificar el problema.
